# Configuration of pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

I've gone through the documentation and read quite a number of articles that I found on Google. However, the below settings:

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
port = 5432
```

pg_hba.conf

```
local   mydb        postgres                scram-sha-256
local   mydb        mydb                    scram-sha-256
```

don't allow me to log into my server.

EDIT: Looks like I just had the wrong password for: If I try to log in as mydb, I get the error in Terminal:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
> failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mydb"

EDIT: Still unable to log in to pgAdmin. In pgAdmin, if I try to log in as postgres I get the error:

> connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: no
> pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database
> "postgres", no encryption

I'm trying to configure based on the principle of least privilege. Starting with local access and working my way out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please give us the exact strings you used to try and login and whether you were asked for a password or not?

Comment: When I tried to log in as mydb user, I input:
psql -U mydb -d mydb
And I was asked for the password.
I also tried log in as postgres user through PgAdmin.

Comment: I just tried logging in as postgres in through terminal and was successful. I changed the mydb password to what I thought I put in for the mydb password and I'm able to log in through terminal with both users now. Not sure why pgAdmin is still throwing a tantrum.

Comment: Please add the information in your response to my comment into the question itself - it's difficult to follow when there's info/data in comments - going back and forth between question and comment can have its own cognitive load - better to have everthing in one place - use comments to notify the person that the info requested has been put into the question.

Comment: I've amended the original question. The only part that I still have problems with is:
EDIT: Still unable to log in to pgAdmin. In pgAdmin, if I try to log in as postgres I get the error:

connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption

Comment: `local` hba rules are about connections via unixsock. They are not used for tcp/ip connections (including loopback). To connect via tcp/ip you also need to allow these connections, for example, `host all all samehost scram-sha-256`

Comment: I think you should read some more documentation, particularly about `pg_hba.conf`. Also, it seems that you didn't set the correct password for user `mydb`.

Comment: Thanks @Melkij I think I understand.

Comment: The database servers log file should give more information about the problem.  Some information it is unwilling to send to the (unauthenticated) client, but will still write to its own log file.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes, logs is something I need to look at more often.